# limiting data set to be used xlim

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, limit

I have lots of files that contain x, y, yerr columns. I read them and save and apply a change on the x values, then I would like to set a limit on the x values I will use afterwards which are the newxval:

```
for key, value in files_data.items():


    file_short_name = key
    D_value_sale = value[1]
    data = pd.DataFrame(value[0])

    if data.shape[1] == 3:
        data.columns = ["x", "y", "yerr"]
    else:
        data.columns = ["x", "y"]

    D = D_value_sale 
    b = 111
    c = 222

    data["newx"] = -c*(((data.x*(1/(1+D)))-b)/b)
    data["newy"] = (data.y-data.y.min())/(data.y.max()-data.y.min()) 
 
    w = data[(data.newx < 20000) & (data.newx > 8000)]
    dfx = w["newx"]
    dfy = w["newy"]

    peak = GaussianModel()
    pars = offset.make_params(c=np.median(dfy))
    pars += peak.guess(dfy, x= dfy, amplitude=-0.5)
    result = model.fit(dfy, pars, dfx)
```

Comment: If you'll share a sample from one of those "lost of files" we could possibly help you more than we could now :)

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: you can just assume any 3 column values. for example from 1000, 19, 1 to 5000, 25, 1. y axis is not important at the moment. the x values from 1000 to 5000 will go through the formula and newxval will be calculated. Then I am trying to limit the newx values between two points.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding correctly what you are asking this is what you could do:

```
for key, value in files_data.items():
    file_short_name = key
    # main = value[1]
    data = pd.DataFrame(value[0])

    if data.shape[1] == 3:
        data.columns = ["x", "y", "yerr"]
    else:
        # Here you should define what happens in case
        # the data isn't what you expected it to be

    data["newx"] = data.x + 1 # Perform whatever transformation you need
    # data["newy"] = data.y * (1.01234) # Etc.
    
    # Then you can limit the newx column by doing:
    data[(data.newx < upper_limit) & (data.newx > lower_limit)]
```

What you're doing won't work if you want to preserve the relationship between columns. When you assign the `data` columns to their own variables `xval`, `yval` and `error` you are implicitely "losing" their relationship.

Comment: Thanks. I see your point and your version of my code also works without adding the limit. However, when I put a limit like: data[(data.newx < "-8000") & (data.newx > "-20000")], I get an error now : TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=float64 and str

Comment: that's because you're using `"-8000"` and `"-20000"`, which are strings (I used the double quotes in my example for syntax reasons, but it may have been a source of confusion, I'll change it). You should `8000` and `20000` (notice: no double quotes) and it should work.

Comment: the error just changed to "None of [Int64Index([8, 9, 7, 10, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0], dtype='int64')] are in the [index]" , I really cant seem to understand why this is not workin

Comment: @JamesLane please update the question with what you're doing now so we can understand better

Comment: sorry, just updated the question. what I try to do is take the new limited newx values, and put them inside a gaussian, along with the newly associated newy values corresponding to the newx ones. but it raises that error now

Answer (score 0):

I'll open with the same caveat of "if I'm understanding you correctly" then the crux of what you are looking for is the boolean array that you have created to apply your limits:

```
data = data[(data[0] >= xlim[0]) & (data[0] <= xlim[1])]
```

This boolean array can be saved and applied to any array of the same shape.

```
idx = (data[0] >= xlim[0]) & (data[0] <= xlim[1])

filtered_data = data[0][idx]
filtered_newxval = newxval[idx]
```

By way of a more complete and independent example, see the code below where this concept can be applied to multidimensional arrays and pandas dataframes

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(42)

x = np.random.randint(0, 20, 10)
y = np.random.randint(0, 20, 10)

print("x", x)
# >>> x [ 6 19 14 10  7  6 18 10 10  3]
print("y", y)
# >>> y [ 7  2  1 11  5  1  0 11 11 16]

xmin = 3
xmax = 17

idx = (x >= xmin) & (x <= xmax)

data = np.vstack((x, y))
print("filtered_data:\n", data[:, idx])
# >>> filtered_data:
#     [[ 6 14 10  7  6 10 10  3]
#     [ 7  1 11  5  1 11 11 16]]

df = pd.DataFrame({"x": x, "y": y})
df["xnew"] = df["x"] * 2
print(df[idx])
# >>>     x   y  xnew
# >>> 0   6   7    12
# >>> 2  14   1    28
# >>> 3  10  11    20
# >>> 4   7   5    14
# >>> 5   6   1    12
# >>> 7  10  11    20
# >>> 8  10  11    20
# >>> 9   3  16     6
```